# PayPal Sandbox Accounts: facilitator and premier types?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

After created an account into PayPal Developer, in Sandbox > Accounts I found: me.facilitator@xxx.com (type=business) and me.buyer@xxx.com (type=premier) .

I found out that I can use me.buyer@xxx.com to emulate a purchase.

And about me.facilitator@xxx.com? Is it possible to emulate a business account, as if I were the owner?

For what exists this email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

facilitator is the business account that is going to be credited after a sandbox purchase